# How to keep List index fixed in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, indexing, fixed

I want to keep the indices of the items in a Java List fixed.

Example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
        a.add(12.3);
        a.add(15.3);
        a.add(17.3);

        a.remove(1);
        System.out.println(a.get(1));
    }
}
```

This will output `17.3`. The problem is that `17.3` was on index 2 and now it's on index 1!

Is there any way to preserve the indices of other elements when removing an element? Or is there another class more suitable for this purpose?

Note: I don't want a fixed size Collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use [`java.util.SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) with `int` keys:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SortedMap<Integer, Double> a = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>();
        a.put(0, 12.3);
        a.put(1, 15.3);
        a.put(2, 17.3);

        System.out.println(a.get(1)); // prints 15.3
        System.out.println(a.get(2)); // prints 17.3

        a.remove(1);

        System.out.println(a.get(1)); // prints null
        System.out.println(a.get(2)); // prints 17.3
    }
}
```

- `SortedMap` is a variable-size Collection
- It stores values mapped to an ordered set of keys (similar to `List`'s indices)

No implementation of [`java.util.List#remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) may preserve the indices since the specification reads:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

Comment: And if you don't want to keep track of the next index yourself, you could just subclass `SortedMap` and add a `public V put(V value)`, and keep track of the next index internally in the subclass.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `a.remove(1)` you could do `a.set(1, null)`.  This will keep all elements in the same place while still "removing" the value at index one.

Comment: this way, i should implement a new Type of Lists ,is there any thing standard ?

Comment: The set method *is* a standard method of the List interface. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29

Comment: "set" is ,surely, standard  , i mean that i want a Standard Class that use this mechanism

Comment: @MhdSyrwan: there can be no such class because the semantics of [`List#remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) require that an implementation "shifts any subsequent elements to the left".

Comment: @maerics well pointed out, I've requested that be added to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the relationship should be always the same between the index and value then use a `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the element with the call to remove set the element to null:

i.e:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
        a.add(12.3);
        a.add(15.3);
        a.add(17.3);

        a.set(1, null);
        System.out.println(a.get(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `HashMap<Integer, Double>`. You could add items using

```
myMap.put(currentMaximumIndex++, myDoubleValue);
```

This way, indices would be unique, if you need sparse storage you'd be reasonably okay, and removing a value wouldn't hurt existing ones.

Comment: +1. This seems to be the most-space-efficient way of storing the values and not changing the index.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the above answer its also suggested you should use `LinkedHashMap<Integer,Double>`, instead of a regular Hashmap
It will preserve the order in which you insert the element.